How do I change the font-weight parameter in mpdf?
The problem is very simple, I can't change the font weight in the text. Everything else changes except for this parameter.
I wanted to change the font weight, but it is this parameter that cannot be changed.
I can't figure out what's wrong?
.text-bold22 {
          font-size: 24px;
          color: #808080;
          font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

      }

<div class="text-bold22">
                
                <?php

if ($familia !== '') {
   echo $familia . ' '; 
} else {
    echo "Не указано";   
}
 

if ($name !== '') {
   echo $name . ' ';  
} else {
    echo "Не указано";  
}



if ($otch !== '') {
   echo $otch;   
} else {
    echo "Не указано";    
}

?>
                
                
            </div>


As far as I know mPDF does not support multiple weights for a single font but you have to add 2 separate fonts - one regular, one bold.
For example
'fontdata' => $fontData + [
    'montserrat' => [
        'R' => 'Montserrat-Regular.ttf',
    ],
    'montserrat-bold' => [
        'R' => 'Montserrat-Bold.ttf',
    ]
],

See more in docs.
